# unmerge css and js files on magento admin back-end

Tags: javascript, html, css, git, magento

I've made some changes on my local. then when i git push my changes to dev environment I don't see them. When I was inspecting my code I noticed that the css on my local are different because the css files on dev are merged.

I would like to know how can i un-merge the js and css files on the dev environment so 
that they looking the same as the ones on my local

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable JS/CSS file merging by doing the following:

1. Go to **System > Configuration > Developer** in your Magento admin
2. Under **JavaScript Settings**, set **Merge JavaScript Files** to `No`
3. Under **CSS Settings**, Set **Merge CSS Files** to `No`
4. Click **Save Config**, and refresh your Magento caches.